# CNN-1D(Seq2point) Timeseries Prediction using Keras Error in Dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network

I am trying to fit a CNN 1D model in keras with Sequence to Point (seq2point) architecture

My data is a time series data.

Input feature is a sensor data (1 value in every 6 second) and output is also a continuous number.
This means my problem is a Regression problem.

**But I am getting Error while running my model**

```
*ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_18_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (176526, 600)*
```

I know I am messing with the dimensions but dont know where.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**link for complete Code in Google Colab**
[GoogleColab](https://github.com/nitin-barthwal/CNN1D/blob/master/CNN_1D.ipynb)

**Creating Model**

```
def create_model(n_timesteps, n_features,n_outputs):
'''Creates and returns the ShortSeq2Point Network
'''
model = Sequential()

# 1D Conv
model.add(Conv1D(filters=30, kernel_size=10, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features), padding="same", strides=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=30, kernel_size=8, activation='relu', padding="same", strides=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=40, kernel_size=6, activation='relu', padding="same", strides=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=50, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', padding="same", strides=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# Fully Connected Layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
#plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)

return model

n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], y_train.shape[1]
# create model
model = create_model(num_time_periods, n_features,n_outputs)
model.summary()
```

**Model**

```html
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_18 (Conv1D)           (None, 600, 30)           330       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_20 (Dropout)         (None, 600, 30)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_19 (Conv1D)           (None, 600, 30)           7230      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_21 (Dropout)         (None, 600, 30)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_20 (Conv1D)           (None, 600, 40)           7240      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_22 (Dropout)         (None, 600, 40)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_21 (Conv1D)           (None, 600, 50)           10050     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_23 (Dropout)         (None, 600, 50)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)          (None, 30000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              30721024  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_24 (Dropout)         (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 600)               615000    
=================================================================
Total params: 31,360,874
Trainable params: 31,360,874
```

**DataSet**

```
Input_feature   Output_Value        
       4              276
       5              276
              ...
      21              667
      20              672
    177126 rows × 2 columns
```

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXFV4.png)

Comment: You are `reshaping` the `Data` twice and that is the reason for the error. Please find this article (https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-convolutional-neural-network-models-for-time-series-forecasting/) which has a comprehensive `End to End code` for `Uni-Variate` and `Multi-Variate Time Series Analysis` using `Conv-1D`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as rightly mentioned by Tensorflow Support. Here you are reshaping data couple of times, which altered input data (i.e x_train) shape from 3 dimensions to 2.

Please refer complete working code in below

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import math
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error,  mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Reshape
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.utils import to_categorical
#from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from keras import backend
import keras
#from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout


from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import plotly.graph_objs as go
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nitin-barthwal/CNN1D/master/dataset.csv'
rescaled = pd.read_csv(url)
print('Shape : ',rescaled.shape)
rescaled.sample(10)

def Reshape_data(df, time_steps, step):
    '''
    time_steps is the number of observations that I have in a sample 
    steps is the number with which I am shifting or advancing to create a new sample. 
    for eg if data is [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] with time steps = 5 and step=3 then 
    sample 1: [1,2,3,4,5]
    sample 2: [4,5,6,7,8] 
    sample 3: [7,8,9,10,11]
    '''
        
    N_FEATURES = 1   # As i have only one input feature
    segments = []
    output_segments = []
    labels = []
    for i in range(0, len(df) - time_steps, step):
        sensor_load = df['Input'].values[i: i + time_steps]
        segments.append([sensor_load])
        output= df['Output'].values[i: i + time_steps]
        output_segments.append([output])
    # Reshaping
    reshaped_segments = np.asarray(segments, dtype= np.float32).reshape(-1, time_steps, N_FEATURES)
    output_segments = np.asarray(output_segments, dtype= np.float32).reshape(-1, time_steps, N_FEATURES)
    return reshaped_segments, output_segments

TIME_PERIODS= 600

STEP_DISTANCE = 1 # Shifting just 1 observation

x_train,y_train = Reshape_data(rescaled, TIME_PERIODS, STEP_DISTANCE )
print('x_train.shape : ',x_train.shape)
print('y_train.shape : ',y_train.shape)

num_time_periods, n_features = x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]

input_shape = (num_time_periods*n_features)

def create_model(n_timesteps, n_features,n_outputs):
    '''Creates and returns the ShortSeq2Point Network
    '''
    model = Sequential()

    # 1D Conv
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=30, kernel_size=10, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features), padding="same", strides=1))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=30, kernel_size=8, activation='relu', padding="same", strides=1))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=40, kernel_size=6, activation='relu', padding="same", strides=1))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=50, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', padding="same", strides=1))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    # Fully Connected Layers
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='linear'))

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    #plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)

    return model

#n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], y_train.shape[1]
n_outputs=y_train.shape[1]
# create model
model = create_model(num_time_periods, n_features,n_outputs)
model.summary()

callbacks_list = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath='best_model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5',
        monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True),
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='acc', patience=1)
]

model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])

# Hyper-parameters
BATCH_SIZE = 400
EPOCHS = 1

# Enable validation to use ModelCheckpoint and EarlyStopping callbacks.
history = model.fit(x_train,
                      y_train,
                      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                      epochs=EPOCHS,
                      #callbacks=callbacks_list,
                      validation_split=0.2,
                      verbose=1)
```

Output:

```
Shape :  (177126, 2)
Input   Output
76135   0.014060    0.077409
18217   0.013428    0.043602
127749  0.014060    0.069510
160231  0.013902    0.046603
167690  0.000000    0.058294
170048  0.000000    0.054502
137066  0.012954    0.052607
70656   0.000000    0.056556
166391  0.000000    0.064613
78139   0.000000    0.039494

x_train.shape :  (176526, 600, 1)
y_train.shape :  (176526, 600, 1)

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 600, 30)           330       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 600, 30)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 600, 30)           7230      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 600, 30)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 600, 40)           7240      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 600, 40)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, 600, 50)           10050     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 600, 50)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 30000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1024)              30721024  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 600)               615000    
=================================================================
Total params: 31,360,874
Trainable params: 31,360,874
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

354/354 [==============================] - 14s 39ms/step - loss: 0.0081 - mse: 0.0081 - val_loss: 0.0081 - val_mse: 0.0081
```